# How to let typescript know the function type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Assume there is a function named `attachName`:

```
function attachName(saga: Generator) { ... }
```

There is a saga function which is actually a generator function:

```
function* sagaFunc(){ ... }
```

Now, if I do the following:
`attachName(sagaFunc)` it complains about the `sagaFunc` that I've passed into `attachName`

Sample is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-leftpad-kwogx?file=/src/index.ts)

Now, if I change `attachName` signature to

```
function attachName(saga: () => Generator)
```

the error doesn't appear anymore.

But it doesn't seem to be correct.
Can I somehow explicitly set `Generator` type to my `sagaFunc`. Maybe after this, the function `attachName` will not complain.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the `Generator` interface:

```js
/// <reference lib="es2015.iterable" />

interface Generator<T = unknown, TReturn = any, TNext = unknown> extends Iterator<T, TReturn, TNext> {
    // NOTE: 'next' is defined using a tuple to ensure we report the correct assignability errors in all places.
    next(...args: [] | [TNext]): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    return(value: TReturn): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    throw(e: any): IteratorResult<T, TReturn>;
    [Symbol.iterator](): Generator<T, TReturn, TNext>;
}
```

As you might have noticed, `Generator` is actually an `Iterator` - it extends `Iterator` and has `next`, `return` ... methods.

Hence, `Generator` is just an object, while `function* sagaFunc(){ ... }` is a function which returns a `Generator` object.

So, this type `function attachName(saga: () => Generator)` is perfectly valid, because `attachName` function expects a function which returns a `Generator`.

It is a common to say that `sagaFunc` is a generator function but in fact this is a function which returns a `Generator`

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to be sure, that I am not missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
function attachName(saga: () => Generator)
```

is correct, because you are actually passing a function which returns a generator. If you want to pass only the generator returned by `sagaFunc` and preserving the signature of `function attachName(saga: Generator) { ... }`   you can do it like this:

```
attachName(sagaFunc());
```

Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-pascal-cn55c?file=/src/index.ts)